# Subtract arrays entries which have one key->value in common

Tags: php, arrays

I have small problem with arrays substraction. I think its simple but today I just can't figure it out.

I have two arrays:

First : $freeUsers

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#122 (7) {
["is_on_job"]=>
int(0)
["user_id"]=>
int(28)
["first_name"]=>
string(4) "John"
["last_name"]=>
string(5) "Johna"
["phone"]=>
string(12) "+17279028012"
["distance"]=>
float(3.4272831099407)
["pickup_status"]=>
string(4) "done"
}
```

Second $busyUsers

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#123 (7) {
["is_on_job"]=>
int(1)
["user_id"]=>
int(28)
["first_name"]=>
string(4) "John"
["last_name"]=>
string(5) "Johna"
["phone"]=>
string(12) "+122222222"
["distance"]=>
float(3.4272831099407)
["pickup_status"]=>
string(4) "picked_up"
},
{
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#115 (7) {
["is_on_job"]=>
int(1)
["user_id"]=>
int(3)
["first_name"]=>
string(4) "Eva"
["last_name"]=>
string(5) "Gross"
["phone"]=>
string(12) "+1711111111"
["distance"]=>
float(3.4272831099407)
["pickup_status"]=>
string(4) "picked_up"
}
```

Now I have to substract from array $freeUsers all entries from $busyUsers where user_id is the same. (In this case $freeUsers will be empty after substraction. )
I tried to do that, but without success.
How can it be done?

Thank you

Comment: Get an array of busy user IDs: `$busy_user_ids = array_map(function($u){ return $u['user_id']; }, $busy_users);`
Then filter the free user array: `array_filter($free_users, function($f) use ($busy_user_ids) { return !in_array($f['user_id'], $busy_user_ids); })`

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP 7+, you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), which is when it added support for objects as input.  This can be used to index both arrays by the user_id and then use [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to get the difference...

```
$result = array_diff_key(array_column($freeUsers, null, "user_id"), 
    array_column($busyUsers, null, "user_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @TomLankhorst suggested, array_filter would be good, also, since your $busyUsers holds an array of objects, i don't think this can be simpler, if they where arrays, instead of an auxArray we could use `array_column()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```php
$auxArr = array();
foreach($busyUsers as $bU ){
   array_push($auxArr, $bU->user_id);
}

array_filter($freeUsers, function($value, $key) {
    return in_array($value->user_id, $auxArr);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
```